# .hover() keeps repeating while element is still hovered

Tags: jquery, hover, repeat

I'm getting a weird behaviour from the jQuery `.hover()` method. I have `img`'s and each of them should display the next container `.item-info` on hover. I'm using this code:

```
  $('img.thumbnail-class').hover(function() { 
      $(this).next(".item-info").stop(true, true).fadeIn(250); 
  }, function() { 
      $(this).next(".item-info").stop(true, true).fadeOut(250); 
  });
```

And I'm getting this behaviour: When the image `.thumbnail-class` is hovered, the next `.item-info` fades in, fades out, fades in and stays. When the mouse is still hovering the image, but moving, the `.item-info` fades out and in again, etc. until the mouse leaves the image.

I already tried the recommended `.stop()` method for hovering problems, but it seems it didn't help.

?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `.item-info` cover `img.thumbnail-class`?

Comment: yes, it has height 100% and width 100% of the img.thumbnail-class.

Comment: fiddle your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`mouseout` fires if an element is covered by another (therefore the second hover function is called) So your scenario can't work. Instead do something like this:

```
$('img.thumbnail-class').mouseover(function() { 
      $(this).next(".item-info").fadeIn(250).one("mouseout", function(){
          $(this).fadeOut(250); 
      });
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8nfyjux/